# Javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css, visibility

Just realised that my site does *not* work in IE correctly. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. In IE the problem is, the elements effected by javascript, just aren't appearing. I have Javascript enabled, so I don't know how its any different from the other browsers.

It's when I'm using the `toggle_visibility` function:

```
function toggle_visibility_1(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display = 'inline') 
    e.style.display = 'none';
}
function toggle_visibility_2(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display = 'none') 
    e.style.display = 'inline';
}
```

The website is here: http://www.dillonbrannick.com/
of course, there won't be a noticeable problem unless in IE and if in IE it may not be obvious, so hopefully I've described well enough.

So It seems that I somehow **fixed the problem** works just as it should see here if you want: http://testerwebby.tumblr.com/  So I don't know what I did, but I'll soon have it rolled out to my website, Thanks for all the help.

Comment: `=` and `==`/`===` is quite different in Javascript. You're lucky it works in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Make it an answer!

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Don't have time now to make a quality answer out of it right now. I hope someone will go further than copying my comment and posting it as an answer :).

Comment: Since IE treats assignment and equality operators in the normal way, this probably won't fix the problem (although it should definitely be corrected). There's probably an element with a `name` attribute matching the `id` being selected or something.

Answer (score 8):

You're performing assignment, not comparison:

```
// Sets the value of display
if ( e.style.display = 'none' )
```

You should be using `==` (value) or `===` (value and type) to test equality:

```
// Tests the value of display
if ( e.style.display == "none" )
```

If all you want to do is toggle between `inline` and `none`, the following would perform that better:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display === "none") ? "inline" : "none" ;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uyawop/edit#javascript,html

Comment: In general, go with triple equality, since it does stricter comparing than double equality. In this case, there is no difference though.

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work, when I just change the = 'none' to =='none', it works, but when I do it on both funtions nothing happens.

Comment: whoops, hit enter to return, but it posted. So when I use your third piece of code in place, it toggles on and off constantly, where I want it it to just toggle once. And even when I used your code, it still didn't seem to work in IE. Thanks For all the response, but I think there is still something wrong.

Comment: @dillonbrannick If it's toggle on and off constantly, then you're calling the function constantly. Where do I see this function in use on your site?

Comment: well I don't have on it, because it wasn't working the way I want it too, plus my site is set up to use 2 functions whereas yours is just a singular one, unless there is a way to modify your code to just toggle once, but as you've probably already guessed I'm no programmer, here's the webpage: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70582811/webtest.html Thanks for your interest and help.